# Wearing Winter Bash hats although Winter Bash is over?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

It's still cold outside.

Look at my profile picture, I don't have long hair. Is there anything wrong if I put on a Winter Bash hat, although the Winter Bash period has ended?

Technically, I have taken a screenshot of my avatar wearing a hat and I could just upload that screenshot as my avater image. I just wanted to know if this is considered as abuse. I don't want to affront anybody.

Comment: [This user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178816/travis-j) is still [enjoying the winterbash](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qc7Mb.png). You can too.

Comment: If the downvoter would explain the downvote I would be able to learn which questions to ask and which questions not to ask.

Comment: @ThomasW. there's nothing wrong with your question. Just as we hold the magical fun of Winter Bash in our hearts all year 'round, others are just perennial grinches. Don't sweat it.

Comment: @Thomas - There is nothing wrong in your question. In fact you have asked it whether it is abuse or not before doing so. +1 :-)

Comment: I agree with the crowd here, tis a good question +1 also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, feel free to use any hats in your avatar that you have saved from the event. Near the end, Balpha had this interesting idea of making a button that lets you create a new avatar based on your current avatar and the hat you were currently wearing, I think that would be a rather neat feature for next year, in my humble opinion :)

I also *really* look forward to that time of year every year, ever since the first Winter Bash - it's just an amazing amount of fun and I frequently smile while recalling it.

Answer (score 4):

You can upload your avatar with wearing the hat.
It won't be considered as abuse.

Comment: Well, that depends on how you look in pink. Some people should just _never_ wear pink, even after labor day.